# How to apply Cookie on REST web service URL using iOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cookies

I have made a REST request from my application, and i am able to get data properly. Now i want to apply an authentication cookie on this web service URL. How can we do this. Please help. Below is my current code.

**CallRestParser.swift** - In this processRequest method will be called from some view controller. processRequest method will receive the web service URL and send request to RESTParser class. getReceiveData is a delegate method which will be called after successful connection.

```
protocol UpdateProjectUIDelegate{
    func UpdateProjectUI(data:NSDictionary)
}
class CallRESTParser: NSObject, RESTParserDelegate {
    var rest1=RESTParser()
    var projectDelegate: UpdateProjectUIDelegate?
    func processRequest(url:String) {
        var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)
        var createrequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: nsURL!)
        createrequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        rest1.delegate = self
        rest1.httpRequest(createrequest)

    }

    func getReceiveData(recvData:NSMutableData,sender:RESTParser){
        var error: NSError?

        var jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(recvData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

        if error != nil{
            print("Error occured  \(error?.localizedFailureReason)")
            return
        }
        println(jsonResult.count)
        projectDelegate?.UpdateProjectUI(jsonResult)
        //var updateUI = ProjectDetails_tab()
        //updateUI.updateUI()


    }
}
```

**RESTParser.swift** -

```
protocol RESTParserDelegate{
    func getReceiveData(data:NSMutableData,sender:RESTParser)
}


class RESTParser: NSObject, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {

    var receiveData: NSMutableData!
    var requestConnection: NSURLConnection!
    var delegate: RESTParserDelegate?

    func receiveData(resData:NSMutableData){
        receiveData = resData
    }

    func requestConnection(reqConn:NSURLConnection){
        requestConnection = reqConn
    }

    func httpRequest(myRequest:NSMutableURLRequest){
        self.requestConnection = NSURLConnection(request: myRequest, delegate: self)

    }
    // NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse){
        self.receiveData = NSMutableData()

    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData){
        self.receiveData.appendData(data)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection){
        //if let revData = receiveData{
        self.delegate?.getReceiveData(receiveData, sender: self)
        //}else
        //{
          //  NSLog("No data : nil")
        //}
        self.delegate = nil
        self.receiveData = nil
        self.requestConnection = nil
    }
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError){
        NSLog("Failed with error - %@ ",error.localizedDescription)

    }
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace) -> Bool{
        return protectionSpace.authenticationMethod  == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
    }
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge){
        if(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust){
            if(challenge.protectionSpace.host == "domain.com"){
                let credentials = NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust)
                challenge.sender.useCredential(credentials, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
            }
        }
        challenge.sender.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)

    }
}
```

And the Authentication Cookie what we are getting from authSessionCookieKeyVal is something like this - XX-X-SESSION-ID=1_2_1_XXxXXXgSaG1K5aXXXXXXXV . How can i apply this cookie on the above REST call. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass cookie in `header` of `NSMutableURLRequest`

```
    var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)
    var createrequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: nsURL!)

    let cookieArray = NSArray(objects: Cookie1,Cookie2) // Cookie1 and Cookie2 is an object of NSHTTPCookie
    let cookieHeader = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(cookieArray)
    createrequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = NSDictionary(dictionary: cookieHeader)
```

**EDIT**

Cookies are stored in `NSHTTPCookieStorage`

```
    var Cookie1:NSHTTPCookie?  // Cookie Object
    var Cookie2:NSHTTPCookie? // Cookie Object
    let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    let cookieArray = storage.cookies!

    for tempCookie in cookieArray
    {
        if tempCookie.name == "rtFa" // Write your cookie name which you want to search
        {
            Cookie1 = tempCookie as? NSHTTPCookie
            continue
        }
        else if tempCookie.name == "FedAuth" // Write your cookie name which you want to search
        {
            Cookie2 = tempCookie as? NSHTTPCookie
            continue
        }
    }

    if Cookie1 != nil && Cookie2 != nil
    {
        println("Cookie Found")
    }
    else
    {
        println("Cookie Not Found")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Dhaval, Can you also tell me, how do we initialize Cookie1,Cookie2 objects?

Comment: @Davavl we are getting cookie from a authentication SDK and its in this format - PD-S-SESSION-ID=1_2_1_XXxXXXgSaG1K5aXXXXXXXV, which is cookie key value pair.  So how we know what is the name of this cookie? And Before accessing it from NSHTTPCookieStorage we need to set cookie to NSHTTPCookieStorage right??

Comment: Is there any way we can convert String to NSHTTPCookie??